# Add class on hover using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, html, sass

I want to add class on ul that is inside my one li element in nav. My problem is that I want to show list on hover and later click something on it, but when I mouse enter on that li menu shows and when I want to go down and click something menu disappears. I want to do this in vanilla JavaScript.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var dropdownItem = document.querySelector('.dropdown-item');
    var dropdown = document.querySelector('.dropdown');

    dropdownItem.addEventListener('mouseenter', function (e) {
        dropdown.classList.add('dropdown-show');
    });
    dropdownItem.addEventListener('mouseleave', function () {
        dropdown.classList.remove('dropdown-show');
    })

})
```

```css
  .menu {
     list-style: none;
     display: flex;
     width: 30%;
     justify-content: space-between;
     align-items: center;
  }
   .menu li {
     position: relative;
  }
   .menu li a {
     color: #999;
     text-decoration: none;
  }
   .menu .dropdown-item {
     position: relative;
  }
   .menu .dropdown-item .dropdown {
     position: absolute;
     list-style: none;
     top: 5px;
     padding-top: 40px;
     left: -30px;
     visibility: hidden;
     opacity: 0;
     transition: 0.3s;
  }
   .menu .dropdown-item .dropdown .triangle {
     border: 10px solid transparent;
     border-bottom-color: #000;
     width: 0;
     top: 20px;
     left: 50%;
     transform: translateX(-50%);
     position: absolute;
  }
   .menu .dropdown-item .dropdown.dropdown-show {
     opacity: 1;
     visibility: visible;
  }
   .menu .dropdown-item .dropdown li {
     background-color: #000;
     padding: 10px 20px;
     font-weight: lighter;
  }
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">O Firmie</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <div class="triangle"></div>
            <li><a href="#">Aktualności</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Nasz team</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Historia</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Galeria</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why not use css for that?

Comment: You could probably do this entirely with CSS if you're just looking to show / hide things.

Comment: @DomenikReitzner I know how to do this in css, but I need to do this with JS, i mean someone want :)

Comment: Can you change it to include regular CSS so it can run in a snippet?

Comment: Was about to write the same thing....

Comment: Done, can u check now ?

Comment: Yep - that works as I expected now.  Try running the snippet and let us know what's wrong with it.

Comment: Lol... Why it's not working in my browser ?? I copied code, someone can explain me ?

Comment: Is the script running before the menu is included in the page?

Comment: @Freestyle09 what browser are you using? Cannot reproduce

Comment: Google chrome and i felt that it should work but don't know why it doesn't

Comment: Sorry - ignore me.  Wasn't paying attention to the `DOMContentLoaded` handler.

Comment: Lol, I added z-index and it works... Somehow other div blocked it... Lol i cannot belive what I'm am seeing... Someone can add this as an answer

Comment: I use firefox and I run your code it works properly! I can't understand your problem!

Comment: No - you found it so no-one else should add it.  Add it yourself.

Comment: And there was also no problem for me with Chrome browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default Z-index of my li was somehow under other div...

```
.menu {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    width: 30%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Now it works perfectly and menu is not dissapearing on mouseleave in that menu

Thank you guys for help

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot happening with your SCSS and it doesn't work in jsfiddle. That said, I was able to get the basic functionality you were seeking working with this little snippet.

The problem with your code is, that you're adding the `mouseleave` event to the very element (dropdown-item), that shows your dropdown in the first place. The `mouseleave` event should be on the parent (dropdown).

Here's the code:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-item")[0].addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) {
    const parent = e.target.parentElement;
    if (parent && parent.tagName === "LI" && parent.classList.contains("dropdown-item")) {
        const parent = e.target.parentElement;
        parent.children[1].classList.add("active");
    }
});
    
document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown")[0].addEventListener("mouseout", function(e) {
    e.target.classList.remove("active");
});
```

```css
.dropdown {
    display: none;
}
    
.active {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">O Firmie</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <div class="triangle"></div>
            <li><a href="#">Aktualności</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Nasz team</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Historia</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Galeria</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
</ul>
```

** Note that this gives you a quick idea of how to go about it. It's neither perfect, nor efficient code.*

Answer (score 0):

Use "mouseover" event instead of "mouseenter" and "mouseout" instead of "mouseleave".

Comment: write console.log('hi') in your mouseover event and u will see why not

Answer (score -4):

You can use something like this:

```
<ul class="dropdown" onmouseover="hoverTrue($event)" onmouseout="hoverOut($event)">

function hoverTrue(event) {
 event.target.style.display = 'block'; 
 //or add class
 event.target.setAttribute('class', 'something');
}

function hoverOut(event) {
 event.target.style.display = 'none';
 //or add class
 event.target.setAttribute('class', 'something');
}
```

Comment: When you want to use transition u can't style display

Comment: @Freestyle09 you can use `opacity` and `pointer-events: none`

Comment: This isn't relevant.  The OP's code actually works (without simply using inline handlers, which changes nothing).

Comment: Using inline event handlers in HTML is not a good practice. Setting a class on an element using `setAttribute` is far more problem-laden (it wipes out existing classes on the element) than using [`classList.add()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).